# How to scan VIN Barcodes reliably in React Native

Tags: react-native

I've been using react-native-camera to scan barcodes and after noticing that it would not scan every barcode every time, I checked the [MLKit documentation and it doesn't support 1D Barcodes with only one character](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning)

Is there a better library or a different way I can go about scanning VIN Barcodes?

Comment: DId you ever figure it out?